# Mathematical logic: What does '?' mean in these Coq (proof-assistant) tactics?

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

I am new to Mathematical Logic.

I am trying to teach myself the Coq proof-assistant [from these course notes](https://www.lri.fr/~paulin/LASER/course-notes.pdf) and some of the inference rules ('tactics') are as follows:

[image]

What does '?' mean in this table ?

I have tried looking in Wikipedia at some examples of this notation, [here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_rule), but I don't see '?' anywhere.

Comment: See page 6 for explanation about $h$ and $?$

Comment: Somehow I missed this - thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :-)